# Getting stats from a group of instances in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, class, statistics

I'm doing some data analysis with python. I have several data points (~300) where each point has its own global properties (int or float values) and meshing values (i.e. array with 4+ columns).
To ease reading, treating and analyzing each point I created a class as follows (it is a minimum example) :

```
class SimulationPoint:
    def __init__(self, path, scalar1, scalar2):
        self.scalar1 = scalar1
        self.mesh = pd.read_csv(path+'mesh.csv')

    def normalize_input(self):
        return func1(self.scalar1)

    def spot_centers(self, nbr_spots=5):
        points_mesh = self.mesh[self.mesh.value >= self.mesh.value.quantile(0.9)].copy()
        xyz_mesh = points_mesh.drop(['value'], axis=1).to_numpy()
        result = func2(xyz_mesh, n_clusters=nbr_spots)
        return result
```

So my question is, is there some easy way to get stats from several instances of this class ?
For example, plot a histogram or obtain basic statistics (mean, standard deviation, kurtosis, etc...).

For the time being my solution is :

```
# Read data into dict.
path = '../path_to_data/'
full_data = {}
for dp in os.listdir(path):
    dp_path = os.path.join(path,dp)
    full_data[dp] = SimulationPoint(dp_path)
# Loop over dict values.
for key in full_data.keys() :
    x = full_data[key].normalize_input()
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant/effective/(place useful word) to do it ?

P.S. I have more methods/attributes for the class, that is why i decided to create it.
BTW, i'm new with OOP, do not hesitate to comment more broadly about the code implementation.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer `pathlib` over `os.listdir`, etc.  Also, sometimes list comprehensions or dictionary comprehensions make tidy code.  Finally, you might consider iterating over key, value pairs using `dict.items()`.

Like the question, I haven't actually run the code below but something along these lines might do the same as the example in the question.

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("../path_to_data")

full_data = {file.stem: SimulationPoint(file) for file in path.iterdir()}

normed = {k: data.normalize_input() for k, data in full_data.items()}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason to choose `pathlib` over `os.listdir` ?

Comment: I find it generally easier and more intuitive, especially the ability to use the "/" operator to build paths, e.g. `Path(myStartPath) / "subfolder" / "file.txt"`.